# Easiest way to exclude parent cat but not children Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to include posts that are in any child of category 982, but exclude those which are only in category 982?

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-282,-428,,-1046,-1103,-982'); ?>
```

Comment: did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first start by getting the children ID's of the parent category, storing them in a list, and then passing them in as a parameter as an include.

```
<?php

$cats = wp_list_categories('echo=0&title_li=&child_of=982');
$args = array(
    'cat' => array(
        '-282', 
        '-428',
        '-1046',
        '-1103',
        '-982'
    )
);

foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $args['cat'][] = $cat->id;
} 

$posts = query_posts( $args );
```

Something along those lines.

---

You can also take the non-associative array approach.

```
<?php

$cats = wp_list_categories('echo=0&title_li=&child_of=982');

$include_cats = "";

if(!empty($cats)) {
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        $include_cats .= "," . $cat->id;
    } 
}

$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-282,-428,-1046,-1103,-982' . $include_cats );
```